# SSAS partition elimination works from SMSS but not from Excel when issuing the same MDX query

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap

When trying to optimize an Excel pivot report based on an SSAS OLAP connection, I get different results when issuing the MDX query generated by Excel vis SMSS than via Excel. Specifically, a large "Archive" partition, containing data before 2022, is scanned when the MDX is issued from Excel but not when issued from SMSS. The MDX query is limited to Year = 2023. This is the query as captured by SQL Server Profiler when it is sent from Excel:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(Hierarchize(DrilldownMember({{{DrilldownLevel({[Production].[Production Hierarchy].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}}}, 
{[Production].[Production Hierarchy].[Site].&[Porvoo].&[TL4]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)), Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Misc].[Transaction Type].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Materials].[Material Hierarchy].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})), Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Misc].[UoM].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({DrilldownLevel({DrilldownLevel({[Date and Time].[Date Hierarchy].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)},[Date and Time].[Date Hierarchy].[Year],INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)},
[Date and Time].[Date Hierarchy].[Month],INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  
FROM (SELECT ({[Materials].[Material Hierarchy].[Material Group].&[CO2]}) ON COLUMNS , 
({[Date and Time].[Date Hierarchy].[Year].&[2023]}) ON ROWS  
FROM [Flow and Trend View]) 
WHERE ([Date and Time].[Time Offset].[All],[Misc].[Measurement Type].&[FLOW],[Status].[Status Hierarchy].[TAG Status Type].&[Actual],[Measures].[QTY ACT]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

I can see in the Profiler that the "Archive" partition is read when the exact same query is issued from Excel but not from SMSS. This has a huge performance impact since most of the time is spent reading the Archive partition.

How can I get the same performance from Excel as from SMSS, avoiding reading the Archive partition which does not contain any data in the scope of the MDX query?

I have tried setting the "Slice" property of the Archive partition to define the years (before 2022) of data which it contains:

```
{ [Date and Time].[Year].[2014] , [Date and Time].[Year].[2015] , [Date and Time].[Year].[2016] , [Date and Time].[Year].[2017] , [Date and Time].[Year].[2018], [Date and Time].[Year].[2019], [Date and Time].[Year].[2020], [Date and Time].[Year].[2021]}
```

This works great for MDX queries issued from SMSS but not from Excel.